# How to prove Sturmian separation theorem with Rayleigh quotient？

Tags: matrices

Consider a sequence of symmetric matrices
\begin{equation}
A_r=[a_{ij}],~~~i,j=1,2,...,r
\end{equation}
where $r=1,2,...,n$.

Let $\lambda_i(A_r)$, $i=1,2,...,r$ be the i-th eigen value of $A_r$, and

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1(A_r)\ge\lambda_2(A_r)\ge...\ge\lambda_r(A_r)
\end{equation}

How to prove that

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{k+1}(A_{i+1})\le\lambda_k(A_i)\le\lambda_k(A_{i+1})
\end{equation}

with Rayleigh quotient?

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: How does A depend on r?

Comment: This is called the Cauchy Interlacing Theorem, if you are interested. To prove it, start with the min-max theorem for $A_i$, and write it as $PA_{i+1}P^*$ where $P$ is an opportune rectangular matrix

Comment: @Exodd Thanks a lot! I will try it.

Comment: @timur I think $A_{r-1}$ is a part of $A_r$

Comment: The statement is not clear please clarify

Comment: @timur $A_{r-1}=(I_{r-1}~~0)A_r(I_{r-1}~~0)^T$. So $A_r$ does not exactly depend on $r$. The sequence just appears in an nesting manner.(I'm not sure if I express this right. I'm not a native speaker.) But I figure it out eventually. It turns out that I made a stupid mistake when using the min-max theorem. Anyway, thx for your reply!